# Iterate through n coins flipping these obtaining all possible combinations.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, combinations

If I have let say n coins all facing the same way. Is there an iterative method for turning these coins, one at a time, until all possible combinations have occurred one and only one time?

This is actually a programming problem I have been thinking about but I think the coin example suits well.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [Gray codes](http://enwp.org/gray_code). (“Gray code is a binary numeral system where two successive values differ in only one bit.”)